# Download Directory with SSE-C using TransferManager AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager, s3transfermanager

I have a directory in a bucket on `S3`, which contains multiple file , previously I use to download whole directory using `TransferManager` like this

```
MultipleFileDownload myDownload = TransferManager.downloadDirectory(
                bucketName,
                storagePath,
                new File(downloadDirectoryPath));
```

but now I need to download this using `SSE-C` since they are encrypted .

After my research I have come to know that I can only download a single file using SSE-C but not whole Directory in `v1` of `AWS SDK`.

Is there any workaround to do this?

Or should I download every single file within that directory ( which doesn't seem to me an efficient solution to me)?

Thanks in advance!